# Python: iterate through list and check for matching sub-string in specific parts of string

Tags: string, list, python-2.7

for all the strings in a list of strings, if either of the first two characters of the string match (in any order) then check if either of last two strings match in specific order.  If so, I will ad an edge between two vertex in graph G.

Example: 
d = ['BEBC', 'ABRC']

since the 'B' in the first two characters and the 'C' in the second two characters match, I will add an edge.  I'm fairly new to Python and what I have come up with through previous searches seems overly verbose:

```
for i in range(0,len(d)-1):
    for j in range(0,len(d)-1):
        if (d[i][0] in d[j+1][:2] or d[i][1] in d[j+1][:2]) and \
        (d[i][2] in d[j+1][2] or d[i][3] in d[j+1][3]):
            G.add_edge(d[i],d[j+1])
```

The next step on this is to come up with a faster way to iterate through since there will probably only be 1 to 3 edges connecting each node, so 90% of the iteration test will come back false. Suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: It would probably be more efficient to check the last characters first.

Comment: @ I'L'l Why is that?

Comment: You have 'regex' in your tags. I don't think that there is a faster solution with regexes.

Comment: To answer at ILI's place : not all conditions in the if statement are executed, only those, from left to right, that are needed to know the final result. In `(a or b) and (c or d)`, if a evaluates to true, b is not evaluated, because `a or b` will always be true. If `a or b` is false, c and d will not be evaluated. `d[i][0] in d[j+1][:2]` is more expensive than `d[i][2] in d[j+1][2]`.

Comment: @ Lorenz Meyer - Good point.  Thank you for the feedback.  So it sounds like I'm not missing any major shortcuts or a more "Phythonic" expression then.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that the last character of each list item needs to absolutely match in the same place it's less expensive to check for that first. The code is otherwise doing unnecessary work even though it really doesn't need to. Using `timeit` you can determine the difference in calculation time by making a few changes, such as checking for the last characters first:

```
import timeit

d = ['BEBC', 'ABRC']

def test1():
    if (d[0][len(d[0])-1] is d[1][len(d[1])-1]):
        for i in range(0,2):
            if(d[0][i] in d[1][:2]):
                return(d[0],d[1])

print(test1())                
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=test1, number=1000000))
```

**Result:**

```
('BEBC', 'ABRC')
2.3587113980001959
```

**Original Code:**

```
d = ['BEBC', 'ABRC']

def test2():
    for i in range(0,len(d)-1):
        for j in range(0,len(d)-1):
            if (d[i][0] in d[j+1][:2] or d[i][1] in d[j+1][:2]) and \
            (d[i][2] in d[j+1][2] or d[i][3] in d[j+1][3]):
                return(d[i],d[j+1])

print(test2()) 
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=test2, number=1000000))
```

**Result:**

```
('BEBC', 'ABRC')
3.1525327970002763
```

Now let's take the last list value and change it so that the last character `C` does not match:

```
d = ['BEBC', 'ABRX']
```

**New Code:**

```
None
0.766526217000318
```

**Original:**

```
None
2.963771982000253
```

This is where it's obviously going to pay off in regard to the order of iterating items — especially considering if 90% of the iteration checks could come back false.